# How to turn a char(0-9) into int in java?

Tags: java, char

```
char c = '7';
int i = c - '0';

// Here value of '0' is 48 and c = '7' is 55. Therefore, i = 55 - 48 or 7;
```

More example:

```
String s = "453467"
```

Here, you may need the integer value located at 3rd cell.
You can first make a char variable. Then convert the char variable into an int.

```
char c = s.charAt(3);
int i = c - '0';
```

Sometimes this thing is needed for solving programming problems and to take the input from the user as an string.

Can you tell me the other ways to convert them. This will be very helpful for me to solve problems. THANKS!!

Comment: If you intended to answer your own question, that is allowed, but please post only the question here at the top, and post your answer as an answer separately below.

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question.  What is your doubt?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Integer class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

`int yourInt = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString('0'));

Comment: `The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (char)`

Comment: Really? I guess you can use `String.valueOf('0')` then

Answer (score 2):

You want:

[Character.getNumericValue(char ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char))